# Unable to make network call

Tags: swift, network-programming

I'm trying to make a network call to forecast.io for a weather forecast. My code looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let apiKey = "" // 32 letters and numbers

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://developer.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
    let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "37.8267,-122.423", relativeToURL: baseURL)

    let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: forecastURL!, options: nil, error: nil)

    println(weatherData)
}


}
```

The println() just returns nil. When I log in to forecast.io I see I haven't yet made a call. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The `NSData(contentsOfURL: ...)` method has an **error parameter**. Why don't you use that to get more information about the problem ??

Comment: How would I go about that. I'm very inexperienced so I have no idea. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: martin r, how would I use the error parameter?

Comment: See "Error Reporting" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in url:

```
"https://developer.forecast.io/forecast/
```

should be

```
"https://api.forecast.io/forecast/
```